# Determining if an image has a particular colour spectrum

Tags: java, image, colors, pixel

I'm wondering if there are any algorithms out there written in Java currently for determining if an image has a low range of different pixel colours contained within it.

I'm trying to detect placeholder images (that typically consist of high percentages of single colours (typically white and grey pixels) as opposed to full colour photos (that consist of a plethora of multiple colours).

If nothing exists, I'll write something myself (was thinking about sampling an arbitrary pixels in random positions across the image or averaging out all pixel colours contained across the image) and then determining quantities of the different colours I find. There may be a trade off between speed and accuracy depending on the methodology used.

Any advice / pointers / reading material appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: Do you want to determine the number of unique pixel values in the image?

Comment: Yes. a low percentage of uniques across the image would indicate a placeholder image. Higher percentage more likely to be full colour photographs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it would be:

```
final BufferedImage image = // your image;
final Set<Integer> colours = new HashSet<Integer>();

for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
    colours.add(image.getRGB(x, y));
  }
}

// Check your pixels here. In grayscale images the R equals G equals B
```

You can also use the Java Advanced Imaging(JAI) since it provides a Histogram class:

```
package com.datroop.histogram;

import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.media.jai.Histogram;
import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
import javax.media.jai.ROI;
import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;

public class HistogramCreator {

private HistogramCreator() {        
}

public static int[] createHistogram(final PlanarImage image) {
    // set up the histogram
    final int[] bins = { 256 };
    final double[] low = { 0.0D };
    final double[] high = { 256.0D };

    Histogram histogram = new Histogram(bins, low, high);

    final ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();

    pb.addSource(image);
    pb.add(null);
    pb.add(1);
    pb.add(1);

    final RenderedOp op = JAI.create("histogram", pb);
    histogram = (Histogram) op.getProperty("histogram");

    // get histogram contents
    final int[] local_array = new int[histogram.getNumBins(0)];

    for (int i = 0; i < histogram.getNumBins(0); i++) {
        local_array[i] = histogram.getBinSize(0, i);
    }

    return local_array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String filename = "file://localhost/C:/myimage.jpg";
        System.setProperty("com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib", "true");
        // Create the histogram
        int[] myHistogram = createHistogram(JAI.create("url", new URL(filename)));
        // Check it out here
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myHistogram));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A simple low-overhead approach would be to do a histogram of the Red, Green and Blue component values separately. There would only be 256 colour levels for each so it would be quite efficient - you could build each histogram in an `new int[256]` array.

Then you just count the number of non-zero values in each of the histograms and check whether they all meet some threshold (say at least 20 different values in each would imply a photograph)

An alternative approach would be to create a HashSet of colour values in the image, and keep adding to the HashSet as you scan the image. Since HashSets hold unique values, it will store only the unqique colours. To avoid the HashSet getting too large, you can bail out when the size of the HashSet hits a pre-determined threshold (maybe 1000 unique colours?) and conclude that you have a photograph.